# Find top 4 most common object in list

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

Let's say I have a list of "Suggestions". I need to get TOP 4 video id's.

```
public class Suggestion{

   static allSuggestions = new ArrayList<Suggestion>();       

   int id;
   String videoId;

   public Suggestion(int id, String videoId){
     this.id = id;
     this.videoId = videoId;
     allSuggestions.add(this);
   }

   public String getVideoId(){
     return videoId;
   }

   public static List<Suggestion> getAllSuggestions(){
      return allSuggestions;
   }
}
```

I tried this:

```
Suggestion.getAllSuggestions()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Suggestion::getVideoId, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

But it only returned one, most common video id and not top 4.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the entries *descending* by count, then select the first 4 using `limit`:

```
Suggestion.getAllSuggestions()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Suggestion::getVideoId, Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue).reversed()) // Sort descending by count
    .limit(4) // Top 4 only
    .forEach(System.out::println); // Print them, one per line
```

Comment: You can also use `.sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())`

Comment: @PaulLemarchand or `.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))`